# Jquery Slide, Hide and Show Div

Tags: jquery, html, slide

I'm trying to put together what seems to be a simple jquery function but i'm having some problems on figuring out the best way to go about it.

Here is what i have so far - jsfiddle.net/f5WE3/1

It generally does what i'd like it to do.

One question would be how would i make it continuous? so that after the third div has slid up the first div would then slide up and so on,

thanks for any help.

Comment: Show the code you've tried

Comment: May be useful to you `http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/`

Comment: Please add some of your code you have tried ?

Comment: Sorry, should have put my code in. Will do so when back at work in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem you are facing, you should not slide down images one by one, you have to make a continuous image, it doesnt mean that you have to create a single image of larger width, I have done that by placing images in a horizontal way and then change the position of the container div. Please check the link below for more clear understanding and download the code and play around it.

[Creating image slide using html and css without any plugin.](http://jforjs.com/creating-image-slider-html-css-without-plugin/)